# Grails Optimum way to save users avatar photos and show them in GSP?

Tags: image, grails, gsp, avatar

Which folder should I use to save users avatar photos in Tomcat container, and how can I show it in view?

I know that it must be outside of war file, but I cannot access images with image tag which is outside of extracted war folder. An example on uploading and showing user profile photos is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? SO is for helping with problems, not providing whole solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If they're just small avatars, you could consider persisting them to your database. When you need to display them again you can fetch them from the db and write them to the response's outputstream.

Here's an example of how to do this:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Load-image-from-database-and-show-it-in-a-gsp-td4644393.html

Comment: i donw want to store in db

Answer (score 0):

Acually Tomcat aren't good in serving static file, so it's very common to put a "frontend" in front of your Java app. Usually it's [Nginx server](http://nginx.org/). If you aren't using Nginx, I strongly suggest to start using it, Nginx can give you up to 5x speedup.

With Nginx you can store/and server images from any directory:

```
server {
  location ~ ^\/(css|js|images)\/.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|css|js)$ {
    root PATH_TO_WEBAPP;
  }
  location ~ ^\/avatar\/.*$ {
    root PATH_TO_AVATARS;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header   Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Where:

- PATH_TO_WEBAPP is where tomcat have extracted you app (`/etc/tomcat/webapps/myapp`)
- PATH_TO_AVATARS is your directory for storing avatars (`/etc/my_avatars`)
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080` just forward all other requests to Tomcat on `localhost:8080`

So, you'll be able to store avatars in own directory from Grails, and serve them through Nginx. For end user it will be a url like `/avatars/myavatar.png`, so you can use 
`resource` tag as usual:

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'avatars', file: 'myavatar.png')}" />
```